# Resume not compiling due to extra alignment tab

Tags: tables, sharelatex, cv

I'm a new LaTeX user and am currently using a template on ShareLatex to create my resume. I changed some things and now im having compilation errors. The compiler should be XeLaTeX

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   
%for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
% an alternative to Layaureo can be ** \usepackage{fullpage} **
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use


%CV Sections inspired by: 
%http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/26
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
%Tweak a bit the top margin
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

%Italian hyphenation for the word: ''corporations''
\hyphenation{im-pre-se}

%-------------WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{2mm}{0.65\paperheight}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}

%WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
%\font\wm=''Baskerville:color=787878'' at 8pt
%\font\wmweb=''Baskerville:color=FF1493'' at 8pt
%{\wm 
%   \begin{textblock}{1}(0,0)
%       \rotatebox{-90}{\parbox{500mm}{
%           Typeset by Alessandro Plasmati with \XeTeX\  \today\ for 
%           {\wmweb \href{http://www.aleplasmati.comuv.com}{aleplasmati.comuv.com}}
%       }
%   }
%   \end{textblock}
%}

\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' %for use with \LaTeX command
\section{Work Experience}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
 Current & Lab Consultant at x University\\Sep. 2016 &
\footnotesize{Ensured printers were all working and were filled. 
Ensured labs were clean. 
Provided technical assistance to students, and faculty when needed.}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
 \textsc{Sep. 20xx-Aug. 20xx} & Teaching Assistant at x\\&
\footnotesize{Helped students who were having trouble with the subject matter.
 Ensured that all students were focused on their work. Ensured that students got the correct work.
 Ensured all work was returned to students in a timely manner.}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\end{tabular}

\section{Education}
\begin{tabular}{r|}
\textsc{Jun. 20xx-Apr. 20xx} & x Program\\&
\footnotesize{Studied logic, mathematical proofs, induction, graph theory, probability, 
combinatorics and discrete mathematics. Also studied sorting algorithms, divide and conquer algorithms, 
greedy algorithms, dynamic programming, network flows and NP completeness.}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\textsc{Sep. 20xx-Jun. 20xx} & High School\\& 
\footnotesize{x Cum Laude | GPA: x.0/4 }\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have the following errors. Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.

Answer (score 2):

Well,  you missend an second parameter `r` (or `l` or `c`) in your second table.

Just add `r` to the line (or in your case better `p{11cm}`):

```
\begin{tabular}{r|}
```

to get

```
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
```

Complete MWE ( a little bit pretty printed)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
Current   & Lab Consultant at x University\\
Sep. 2016 & \footnotesize{Ensured printers were all working and were filled. 
            Ensured labs were clean. Provided technical assistance to 
            students, and faculty when needed.}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\textsc{Sep. 20xx-Aug. 20xx} & Teaching Assistant at x\\
          & \footnotesize{Helped students who were having trouble with 
            the subject matter.  Ensured that all students were focused 
            on their work. Ensured that students got the correct work.
            Ensured all work was returned to students in a timely manner.}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\end{tabular}

\section{Education}
%\begin{tabular}{r|}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}} % <================================================
\textsc{Jun. 20xx-Apr. 20xx} & x Program\\
         & \footnotesize{Studied logic, mathematical proofs, induction, 
           graph theory, probability, combinatorics and discrete 
           mathematics. Also studied sorting algorithms, divide and 
           conquer algorithms, greedy algorithms, dynamic programming, 
          network flows and NP completeness.}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\textsc{Sep. 20xx-Jun. 20xx} & High School\\
         & \footnotesize{x Cum Laude | GPA: x.0/4 }\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

results in the pdf:

[image: ![enter image description here]